# Optional tagged field 19 vs signature recovery. Can these pub keys ever differ?

Tags: lightning-network

From Bolt-11:

```
A reader
if a valid `n` field is provided:
MUST use the `n` field to validate the signature instead 
  of performing signature recovery.
```

Is this merely a performance optimization? Is there a situation where the declared public key field differs from the public key that would have been recovered from the signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recovery of a public key from an ECDSA signature [is not unique](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18106/49392). This is because the `r` value in a signature is only the x-coordinate of a point, so there are actually two points `R` and `-R` that have the same x-coordinate, and both will give a different public key. Actually, for completeness, you can even end up with [four possible public keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60219/49392) - but this happens with negligible probability.

In bolt-11, a recovery ID which takes values 0, 1, 2, or 3 is used to specify which of these four public keys should be used. But indeed, it is more efficient to simply use the given public key `n`. I don't think there are other practical benefits other than efficiency and perhaps robustness in case something goes wrong during recovery. `n` should always be one of the keys recovered, otherwise signature validation will fail.